# El Capitan Download would not resume

Tags: mac-pro

I started downloading El Capitan and left my computer for a while, but it had gone into the sleep mode and the download was paused. But when I tried to resume it would not start even after restarting my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same situation as well. Just open mission control (4 fingers gesture), click and hold on the El Capitan icon and click remove (or delete). Then reinstall it on the mac app store. It worked for me. Hope it help.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to resume the download through the purchased tab, but still had the same problem (waiting...). But when I tried to download yosemite again the download of EL Capitan has resumed.